# HTTP(S) Request With Javascript and receive JSON data

Tags: javascript, json, xmlhttprequest, httprequest

since I'm new on http(s) request case, I have one case here that must be written on Javascript, hope someone could help me because I've searched everywhere and couldn't find the answer. Here is the case:

However, when the connection rate goes up to 5, I will have to wait until one of them is finished corresponding before sending a request, so that 2 or more of them are not over 5.
In addition, when the response code is not 200, I will retry 3 times. If the response code is still not 200 after retrying 3 times, the error function will pursue. I also must receive the Json data of the response body as an argument function.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function loadXMLDoc()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  else if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status!=200){
    document.write("Error");
  }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","demo_get.asp",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h2>AJAX</h2>
<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Request data</button>
<div id="myDiv"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Please help on comment below or you can suggest me links that could help me with this case. Thanks.

Comment: why didn't you include codes in your question , what you tried so far??

Comment: sorry for that, I've inserted my code above, that's what I've tried so far, I'm stuck on that

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

Concerning the connection rate, you can go multiple directions with this, since it isn't 100% clear what you want. The easiest solution would be to have your asp page return a 'fake error' as a json object and have the `success` function check if the response contains this 'fake error'. If so, resend the request to the server. Or you could have the asp page only send a response, if the connection rate < 5, but that might mean your user ends up waiting longer that expected.

```
var getJSON = function getJSON( resource, success, failure ) {
        var xmlhttp = (window.XMLHttpRequest) ? xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200) {
                retry = 0;
                success(xmlhttp.responseText, 200);
            }
            else failure(xmlhttp.status);
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", resource, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    },
    retry = 0,
    success = function success( response, status ) {
        document.querySelector("#myDiv").textContent = response;    
    },
    failure = function failure( status ) {
        if (retry < 3) {
            retry += 1;
            getJSON("demo_get.asp", success, failure);
        }
        else console.log('ERROR');      
    };
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function( event ) {
    getJSON("demo_get.asp", success, failure);
});
```

Comment: thankyou for the suggest Shilly it's very helpful, btw could you give me  example page for the response like what you've explain?

Comment: Since you're expecting a JSON response and not an html page, just return  the JSON structure of the data. I'm not familiar with asp, so can't help you with the serverside alas.

Comment: no no, the asp is just my assumption, if u could help me with JSON example it'd be great

Comment: Something like `json = {"text":"contentThatNeedsToGoIntoTheDiv","error":false}` and `json = {"text":false,"error":true}`. Then you can change the 'success' function to: `if (response.error) { ... } else { document.querySelector("#myDiv").textContent = response; }`